# Text overflowing within nested flexbox containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to get the content of the first 'message-title' to truncate once it hits the edge of the green container. Instead, it's overflowing outside. I think this is probably a Flexbox quirk - anyone attempted to do something similar?

Added relevant codepen to the bottom of the post.

**Markup**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message-content">
      <div class="message-header">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="message-body">
        <div class="message-body__left">
          AV
        </div>
        <div class="message-body__right">
          <div class="message-main">
            <div class="message-type">

            </div>
            <div class="message-details">
              <div class="message-title">
                Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string
              </div>
              <div class="message-subtitle">
                Blah blah
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message-content">
      <div class="message-header">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="message-body">
        <div class="message-body__left">
          AV
        </div>
        <div class="message-body__right">
          <div class="message-main">
            <div class="message-type">

            </div>
            <div class="message-details">
              <div class="message-title">
                Test string Test string
              </div>
              <div class="message-subtitle">
                Blah blah
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message-content">
      <div class="message-header">
        Header
      </div>
      <div class="message-body">
        <div class="message-body__left">
          AV
        </div>
        <div class="message-body__right">
          <div class="message-main">
            <div class="message-type">

            </div>
            <div class="message-details">
              <div class="message-title">
                Test string
              </div>
              <div class="message-subtitle">
                Blah blah
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  min-width: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.message-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 20%;
  max-width: 80%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: green;
}

.message-header {
  display: flex;
}

.message-body {
  display: flex;
}

.message-body__left {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  background: teal;
  display: none;
}

.message-body__right {
  position: relative;
  background: #eff2f5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.message-main {
  display: flex;
}

.message-type {
  position: relative;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.message-details {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message-title {
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.message-subtitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Relevant Codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGgQdL

Comment: Have you just tried `.message-content { overflow-x: hidden; }`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, you can set `overflow: hidden` on that element, but the ellipsis won't appear because all child elements are still overflowing (you can see that in DevTools)

Comment: Hmm I've just removed `display: flex` from `.message-content` and that seems to produce the desired result! Anyone got an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

`white-space: nowrap` in `.message-title` selector is causing the issue.

**Edit 1.**

Removing `display: flex` from `.message-content` works because for `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis` to work parent container should have a fixed width. With `.message-content { display: flex; }` enabled it's not happening because the width is fluid.

If you absolutely need to keep `display: flex` on the parent you can try to manually add fixed width - `.message-title: { max-width: 234px; }` or `width: 234px`. It works the same except it breaks at small screen size.

```css
* {
  min-width: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.message-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 20%;
  max-width: 80%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: green;
}

.message-header {
  display: flex;
}

.message-body {
  display: flex;
}

.message-body__left {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  background: teal;
  display: none;
}

.message-body__right {
  position: relative;
  background: #eff2f5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}

.message-main {
  display: flex;
}

.message-type {
  position: relative;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.message-details {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message-title {
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.message-subtitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>Cover</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="message">
   <div class="message-content">
    <div class="message-header">
     Header
    </div>
    <div class="message-body">
     <div class="message-body__left">
      AV
     </div>
     <div class="message-body__right">
      <div class="message-main">
       <div class="message-type">
      
       </div>
       <div class="message-details">
        <div class="message-title">
         Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string
        </div>
        <div class="message-subtitle">
         Blah blah
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
   <div class="message-content">
    <div class="message-header">
     Header
    </div>
    <div class="message-body">
     <div class="message-body__left">
      AV
     </div>
     <div class="message-body__right">
      <div class="message-main">
       <div class="message-type">
      
       </div>
       <div class="message-details">
        <div class="message-title">
         Test string Test string
        </div>
        <div class="message-subtitle">
         Blah blah
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
   <div class="message-content">
    <div class="message-header">
     Header
    </div>
    <div class="message-body">
     <div class="message-body__left">
      AV
     </div>
     <div class="message-body__right">
      <div class="message-main">
       <div class="message-type">
      
       </div>
       <div class="message-details">
        <div class="message-title">
         Test string
        </div>
        <div class="message-subtitle">
         Blah blah
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor. Rather than have the text wrap like in your example, I want it to truncate with an ellipsis when it starts to exceed the max-width of the parent container

Answer (score 0):

As @Viktor pointed out, the `white-space:nowrap` was causing your issue.

Beside this, I would suggest to simplify your layout. IMO there is no need for so many containers, or at least you can achieve the same result with few code.

Furthermore, keeping things simple leads to easy solutions. E.g. there is no need to do nothing special to make the blue box take all vertical space due the default value of `align-items`, which is `stretch`, meaning that child items will take all available space in the `cross-axis` (Y in this case). The same occurs with child items of `flex-direction:column` parents, which take all horizontal space.

Please see the code snipped below (vendor prefixes ommited for brevety):

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  padding:1.5rem; 
  max-width:400px; 
  background:red;
}

.message:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.message{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.header{
  background:green;
}

.body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.type{
  flex-basis:20%;
  background:blue;
}

.subtitle{
  flex-grow:1;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="message">
 <div class="header">
  Header
 </div>
 <div class="body">
  <div class="type"></div>
  <div class="subtitle">
   Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Test string Blah blah
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
 <div class="header">
  Header 2
 </div>
 <div class="body">
  <div class="type"></div>
  <div class="subtitle">
   Test string2 Test string2 Test string2 Test string2 Test string Test string Test string Test string Blah blah
  </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've generated this layout using [this tool](http://algid.com/flex-designer), a good starting point to play around, understand and generate `flexbox` layouts.

Comment: Thanks Mario. I agree the markup is potentially too complicated at this point - I think I may be able to simplify a few bits. Similar to my reply to Viktor, in your example the text is wrapping, but I need it to truncate with an ellipsis. I've found that removing `display: flex` from the `.message-content` resolves the issue, but I'm not sure why?

Comment: Not sure Mike. Anyway, I have edited the `subtitle` class in my code snippet to achieve what you asked,